# Where can I find a language code list that includes "OVD" and "OLV"? Are they not included in ISO 639?

Tags: translation, resource-request, standards

The lists here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_ISO_639_codes

seem to be woefully incomplete, because they lack the language codes OLV and OVD (And presumably many others) found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfdalian

With the markup codes in question:

```
{{lang|ovd|Övdalsk}}
{{lang|olv|Ulum Dalska}}
```

Are these language codes not included in ISO 639, and if not; what standard do they come from, and is there a more complete table that I can refer to when looking up language codes?

Comment: I doubt that linguists can help you, but at least, this looks like a resource-request.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page is just out of date. If you check the [edit history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_639:o&action=history) you'll see the latest edit is from 2013, but the [ovd code was only created in 2015](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=ovd).

SIL have [an index](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp) which looks like it could be up to date. It has ovd, but not olv. But [Google has no results for "olv Uvåsiljan"](https://www.google.com/search?q=olv+Uv%C3%A5siljan) or ["olv Ulum Dalska"](https://www.google.com/search?q=olv+Ulum+Dalska) so my guess is that it's either a typo or someone made it up.